# App crash when I touch edittext second time in tablet

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-edittext

My app keeps crashing when I touch on edittext second time in 7 & 10 inch devices. Same app is working fine in mobile devices. I am developing the app for the Landscape Orientation. 
Here is my log

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.android.TabletApp, PID: 15773
 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
 at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1251)
 at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:758)
 at android.widget.Editor$InsertionPointCursorController.getHandle(Editor.java:3621)
 at android.widget.Editor$InsertionPointCursorController.show(Editor.java:3600)
 at android.widget.Editor.onTouchUpEvent(Editor.java:1658)
 at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:7957)
 at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7789)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2326)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2031)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2326)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2031)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2326)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2031)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2326)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2031)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2326)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2031)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2326)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2031)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2326)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2031)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2326)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2031)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2326)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2031)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2326)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2031)
 at  com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2133)
 at  com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1557)
 at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2491)
 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneW indow.java:2081)
 at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7980)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4392)
 at  android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4263)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3809)
 at  android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3859)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3828)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3935)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3836)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3992)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3809)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3859)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3828)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3836)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3809)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6124)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6104)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6058)
 at  android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6254)
 at   android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
 at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
 at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
```

I am using simple edittext. Working fine with mobile devices, not working in  Tablet. The whole app is in Landscape orientation.

Comment: pradip_android : are you use any layout for tablet as well. Please Provide your layout and class file for more details.

Comment: Your are putting your drawable in wrong folder put it in common drawable folder.

Comment: @Janak I have used ScrollView and Linear Layout                          <EditText
                android:id="@+id/customername_edtfield"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/customer_name"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:background="@drawable/square_background" />

Comment: @Pitty I have placed drawables in common folder

Comment: @ pradip_android you have to check and debug your onTouch Event of EdiText, your touch event may have create problem with the code.

Comment: @Janak I have not implemented any listener on Edittext .I am just getting values from edittext.

Comment: @pradip_android, did you manage to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have created following drawables:

```
// for Phones
drawable-ldpi
drawable-mdpi
drawable-hdpi

//for 7 inch tablets
drawable-large-mdpi
drawable-large-hdpi(for Nexus 7)

// for 10 inch tablets
drawable-xlarge-mdpi
```

and put **square_background** in each of them.

Comment: I have created drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-ldpi, drawable-sw600dp , drawable-sw720dp   and all devices taking proper drawables from these folders.

Comment: kgandroid -  I have tried by putting square_background in each of them but still not working

Comment: try this in your manifest: <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true"></supports-screens>

Comment: kgandroid- Thanks, But still not fixed. getting same error